# How do I round the corners of my app's window in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, calayer

I'm trying to round the corners of my entire application's window in swift, like the cash app or bonfire. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in your AppDelegate class

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    window?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    window?.clipsToBounds = true
    window?.backgroundColor = .white
  }
```

And if you are using SceneDelegate class then

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {


          window?.layer.cornerRadius = 110
          window?.clipsToBounds = true
          window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }
```